# Results of Limit unclear and given as an interval

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

When we do this limit

```
  Limit[E^x*(1 + Sin[x]), x -> Infinity]
```

The result is

```
  Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}]
```

Is this saying that the result is in this interval, but that Mathematica cannot determine it?

Shouldn't the result be that the limit does not exist?

As a comparison, Wolfram Alpha returns a [*different result*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+e%5Ex%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29+x+%5Cto+%5Cinfty) altogether.

Comment: Oh darn, I forget what this is called. But it's intentional. If you get an `Interval[]` then the limit does not exist in the freshman-calculus sense of limit.

Comment: It measns that for every $y0 \in [0,\infty]$, exist a sequence  $x_{n}\to \infty$,   such that $e^{x_{n}}(1 + \sin(x_{n}))\to y0$

Comment: This feature is documented and can be turned off by `Method->{"AllowIntervalOutput"->False}`

Comment: There is a cautionary sentence about this in the [documentation of Limit, see Details and Options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html). There are a few examples in [this tutorial, see Finding Limits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SeriesLimitsAndResidues.html#25197). I would have thought it is the [set of all limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point#Accumulation_points_of_sequences_and_nets), as defined by @cvgmt, but the documentation is not very clear about it.

Comment: Look at your function: E^x goes to infinity and (1+Sin[x]) oscillates between 0 and 2. Therefore the whole function oscillates between 0 and 2 E^x with x->Infinity. And that is what MMA tells you.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I thought the interval result of `Limit` gives the limit inferior/superior exactly. But it seems wrong:

```
Limit[Cos[x]+Sin[x],x->Infinity,Method->{"AllowIndeterminateOutput"->False,"AllowIntervalOutput"->True}]
Limit[Cos[x]+Sin[x]//TrigFactor,x->Infinity,Method->{"AllowIndeterminateOutput"->False,"AllowIntervalOutput"->True}]
```

[image]

In case that `Listable` of `Plus` affects the result, we can test

```
Limit[Exp[Cos[x]+Sin[x]],x->Infinity,Method->{"AllowIndeterminateOutput"->False,"AllowIntervalOutput"->True}]
```

[image]

---

As pointed by @user64494, in the documentation of `Limit`:

> Limit returns unevaluated or an Interval when no limit can be found. If an Interval is returned, there are no guarantees that this is the smallest possible interval.

`Mathematica` also suggests to use

> Limit returns Indeterminate when it can prove the limit does not exist. MinLimit and MaxLimit can frequently be used to compute the minimum and maximum limit of a function if its limit does not exist.

In simple cases `MinLimit`/`MaxLimit` can return symbolic results, which are more trustable than `Limit`.

Comment: The output of `Limit[Cos[x]+Sin[x],x->Infinity,Method->{"AllowIndeterminateOutput"->False,"AllowIntervalOutput"->True}]` is correct, but not perfect. Up to the documentation, "Limit returns unevaluated or an Interval when no limit can be found. If an Interval is returned, there are no guarantees that this is the smallest possible interval" .

Comment: @user64494 I'm not saying the result is wrong; I just point out that "Previously I thought the interval result of Limit gives the limit inferior/superior exactly" is wrong.